# REACTJS / Route

Tags: reactjs

Quiero crear 5 paginas en carpetas separadas para un unico proyecto
y añadirles componentes que pueda utilizar en todas ellas
el caso es que **estoy intentando rutear las paginas para verlas en mi `localhost:3000/nombredelapagina` y me sale esto...**

> ./src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve './pages/configuracion'
>   in 'C:\Users\Nicko\Desktop\node\src'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a la izquierda tengo el "App" que sustituí por `index.js` y a la derecha una de las paginas de prueba en este caso `configuracion.js` que está en `./pages/configuracion`

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La routa que declaraste en route, es directamente configuracion.. no es pages/configuracion. No confundas rutas del navegador con donde metes las cosas en tu proyecto, son dos cosas distintas

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta añadir el Router, Switch, etc... te dejo un ejemplo de como tienes que mentar las rutas.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

También el link al proyecto de CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-haze-2e26c

Un saludo.